# Is there a way to freeze the entire SAP HANA Database

Tags: hana

In our project we are implementing an application that requires the SAP HANA database to be frozen. Which means, none of the operations should be allowed except for the read only operations.

Is there a way to freeze the entire database, and then unfreeze it in the later point of stage? Or is there any command to lock all the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no such feature.
You may look into different features like

- backup and restore
- database snapshots
- locking user logins/allowing only read only users

In many situations binding the data change authorization to a set of roles and revoking the authorization from the role might work as well.

- Lars

Comment: I agree - properly using Role based permissions, and revoking the permissions when necessary is probably your best bet.